# Laravel elixir "gulp watch" doesn't watch for Javascript changes

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to use [laravel elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir) and it works fine.

***gulpfile.js***:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});
```

But when I use `gulp watch` it watches only for `scss` files and not `JS` so if I edit `app.js` gulp just doesn't compile it however if I run `gulp` it compiles everythings it's just `gulp watch` that won't work properly.

Comment: This seems to be an open issue: [https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/598](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/issues/598)

Comment: Yes, I've found too something online but no answer, only questions.

Comment: @paolo.basso99 Currently the only solution is downgrading

Comment: @paolo.basso99 Can you add your full `gulpfile.js` file?

Comment: @GerardReches I've updated the answer.

Comment: @paolo.basso99 Can you change `mix =>` to `function(mix)` and try again? Shouldn't be this, but just in case...
Webpack is working for me. I'm using this versions `"laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2"`. There are other issues like I [posted in Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/webpack-not-really-compiling-all-the-time-during-gulp-watch) days ago. I'm not sure if it's related with your issue.

Comment: I've already tried function(mix) but it does not works

Comment: Did you make any progress with this question?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe (but not sure) problem with `webpack`.

So try another way of bundling.

For example try this workaround:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts(['app.js'], 'public/js/app.js');
       .sass('app.scss');
});
```

Also check terminal what it outputs, maybe some error happening when it tries to bundle `app.js` file.

If it will not work, so let's discuss it in comments, because Your problem requires debugging of watcher if it gets event that indicates file changed or not and so on...

maybe OS prevents changing of modification time.

there can be many why-s that prevents that

final recommendation is:

`You have to debug "watch" task in gulp and check if it's getting file change event or not. So if NOT - write just Your own task that will check changes and run webpack.`

Comment: Can i use function like require() using "mix.scripts()"?

Comment: Nope) cuz webpack compiles code to native "old-style" js. but if You know nodejs a bit You can write Your own watcher.

Comment: Actually I've never used node however I know pretty well Grunt and I could set the whole project to work with it instead of laravel elixir but I would prefer to fix webpack in order to use its cool stuffs

Comment: I had something alike on Windows OS + Laravel app in Docker container. I was changing file but watcher in container was not getting file change event because of Windows was setting modification date in NTFS, but in Docker was EXT3 so was incompatible to handle that event, so wrote custom watcher that was periodically walking predefined files and checking md5-sum.

Comment: if You know grunt, so use it, and handle file changes and run webpack on it.

Comment: Yes, I know but still I would know (for personal knowledge) how to fix laravel elixir (if it's possible).